# displaying the proper name for my pdf report

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working with *iReport 4.5.0*, *Spring 3.0.5 Release*. I am using [this link](http://chathurangat.blogspot.in/2012/02/jasperreport-with-spring-mvc-fully.html) as the sample to my project because it matches to my requirement exactly.

Flow of my code is exactly same as this. But the problem is when I am displaying the pdf report it is giving the download prompt and there it is giving as opening pdf but instead of that pdf i want the report name.

How can I get it? I have the same situation for csv files.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you modify the response object, you will get: Corrupted Content Error.
You have to set the value in jasper-view.xml, like this:

```
<bean id="pdfReport"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
      p:url="classpath:chathuranga-sample-report.jrxml"
      p:reportDataKey="datasource"> 

      <property name="headers">
        <props>
            <prop key="Content-Disposition">
                 attachment; filename=pdffilename.pdf
            </prop>
        </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to set the Content-disposition header to the response:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

`fileName` being the name of the file that the browser will display for the PDF report.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet thanks for giving the reply.If you see that link in that we have a ReportsController class in that we have generatePdfReport().No file name is mentioning in that method.It is returning the view name so based on that it is going to the JasperReportsPdfView class and displaying the report.So how can i give the file name can you plz bit clear.Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You decide the file name. Add a HttpServletResponse argument to the generatePdfReport() method, and inside the method, add the code `response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Users.pdf");`. The file name displayed by the browser will be "Users.pdf". If you want another name, then replace Users.pdf by what you want as a name.

Comment: If i give as you mentioned in the previous comment and when click on the download pdf button the below error is getting...The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.